# Count seconds on button long press in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count seconds that how much time the button is pressed (long press) at a time using javascript, is there any function or event which fires at the time of long press of button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mix `mousedown` and `mouseup` events in order to achieve what you want.

Something like this:

```js
var timer = 0,
    timerInterval,
    button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
    timer += 1;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerText = timer;
  }, 1000);
});

button.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timer = 0;
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="timer">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this demo. This is perfect answer for me. But actually i solved it before this :) 

Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

`mousedown` fires when the mouse button is held, `mouseup` when it's released.

With the use of variables, you can determine when a button is being held down and when it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion this is absolutely right but i marked answer as an accepted answer because it is with perfect demo and will help another newbie also 

Thanks :)