# HTML number input - how to increase step size w/ time held

Tags: javascript, html

For number inputs in HTML, is there any way to have it function such that the longer the user holds the stepper arrows, the larger the increment/step size becomes?

For example, we start out at step size=1, but after a few seconds of holding, it will ramp up to 5, 10, 20, ... etc.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Doing a combination of [THIS ANSWER -- timing MouseDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320937/count-seconds-on-button-long-press-in-javascript) and [THIS ANSWER -- incrementing Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127507/incrementing-value-continuously-on-mouse-hold) should do exactly what you need ..

Answer (score 1):

The [`step` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step) controls the quantity added to the value of the input when the stepper is activated.

Using the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) method, we can change this value every X milliseconds.

Using a listener for the input's [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) event, we can start/stop the interval and reset the current step when the mouse is released.

Here's a sample:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('my-stepper');
const label = document.getElementById('my-label');

const defaultStep = 1;
const maxStep = 100000;

let interval;

input.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    const currentStep = Number(input.step);
    if (currentStep < maxStep) {
      input.step = currentStep * 10;
      label.innerText = `Current step is ${input.step}`;
    }
  }, 1000);
});

input.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  input.step = defaultStep;
  label.innerText = `Current step is ${input.step}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="my-stepper" type="number" step="1" value="0">
<p id="my-label">Current step is 1</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is below using mouse event listeners.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#num");
let timer;

elem.addEventListener("mousedown", (evt) => {  
  const inp = evt.target;
  inp.dataset.step = inp.step;
  const initialValue = Number(inp.value);
  timer = window.setInterval(()=>{
    const dir = Number(inp.value) > initialValue ? 100 : -100;
    console.log(Number(inp.step) + dir);
    inp.step = Number(inp.step) + dir;
  },2000);
});

elem.addEventListener("mouseup", (evt) => {
  if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  const inp = evt.target;
  inp.setAttribute('step', inp.dataset.step);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1" id="num">
```